# How can I delete some record by using specific id using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

How can I delete a record using its id?

I currently have the following code:

```
@app.route('/delete/<cid>')
def dele(cid):
    # o= catagory.query.get(cid)
    a=db.session.query(catagory).filter(bool(cid)).delete(synchronize_session='fetch')
    db.session.commit()
    return "deleted"
```

But it will delete the entire data in that table. I only want to delete a specific record by specifying its id

I also use this code to implement that :

```
@app.route('/delete/<cid>')
def dele(cid):
    k=catagory.query.get()
    e = catagory.query.filter_by(cid='"+cid+"').first()
    print (cid)
    a = db.session.delete(e)
    db.session.commit()
    return "deleted"
```

My table name is `catagory` 
and `cid` is the column in `catagory` table

Comment: Note that `filter(bool(cid))` is equivalent to either `filter(False)` or `filter(True)`, depending on what `cid` is. `'"+cid+"'` is just a string containing a quote, a plus, the text cid, and again a plus and a quote.